# How to remove seed without it having any effect on database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, database-migration, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

In my project i used seed to adding some data.My project has several migration.
When I adding new migration, My migration file is very large because it wants to update all data in database.
When I remove seeds and add new migration, it wants to delete data from database.
How can I remove seeds without it hasn't any effect on database?

Comment: Remove the seed, generate the migration, but remove the commands that try to delete the data you don't want from the migration. What matters is that the model snapshot is up-to-date and doesn't try to delete the data in the future.

Comment: @abdusco thans, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework only cares about the model snapshot when generating a migration.
We need to make it think it actually updated the DB, without removing the records.

1. Remove the code that seeds your DB.
2. Generate a new migration, it should have the commands that try to remove the seeded records from the DB. Delete those commands.
3. Apply the (now defunct) migration

Your model snapshot is now up-to-date and nothing has been deleted from the DB.

If you generate a new migration, it should turn out empty, meaning our model snapshot is truly up-to-date.