# Entity framework - Removing data seed without removing data from existing databases keeps old seed data for new databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am switching from modelBuilder.Entity<>().HasData(...)  to a custom initialization by asking questions to an admin user the first time they login to my Blazor server side webapp.

The problem I am having is that if I delete the HasData lines, this rows are deleted by EF in the database.  This is not desired since there are production DBs using this information, it will just break everything.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565905/how-to-remove-seed-without-it-having-any-effect-on-database) that the solution is to edit the migration and delete all the Up and down code that contains the delete seed lines and restore lines for that migration.

This works good for old databases, but for new databases the old seed data shows up.

Is there a way to keep the seed data for existing databases but prevent new databases from using this old seed?

Answer (score 1):

After getting in touch with someone on the development team, I figure a way to do this.  It is not the recommended solution but so far it is the only way.

Some considerations must be taken:

- Using HasData in the future for the same data may fail.
- It requires editing the migration files containing the fluent code (even the old ones that have already been applied)
- Wrong modification of the migration files may break future migrations.

So these are the steps I took:

1. I deleted the code that generated the Seed (the lines in c# that contained HasData)
2. I added a migration, but I did not update the database.
3. I deleted in all the fluent code that contain the migrationBuilder.InsertData(), migrationBuilder.UpdateData() and migrationBuilder.DeleteData() lines related to the seed I wanted do delete.
4. Update the database with the migration (that should be just the empty up and down methods).

After doing this, I can confirm that the data in an existing Database is kept, and that in a new database no seed is added.

I also tested to make sure I can create new migrations and update the database, and everything worked fine.

I hope this helps someone else.